# How to cast IList to ObservableCollection<T>

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

I have an UserControl which has `ItemsSource` dependency property and its type is IList.

How can I cast IList to `ObservableCollection<T>`. But I only know Type of `T`. My user control is non-generic. Also I must not change its reference.

In this way, I want to catch `CollectionChanged` event of ObservableCollection

I tried this, but it gives compile error.

```
public IEnumerable ItemsSource
{
    get { return (IList)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
}

private void OnItemsSourceChanged()
{
    Type type = ItemsSource.GetType().GetGenericArguments().ElementAt(0);

    ObservableCollection<object> list = ItemsSource.Cast<object>();
    list.CollectionChanged += list_CollectionChanged;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CollectionChanged` is defined in INotifyCollectionChanged interface. `ObservableCollection<T>` implements INotifyCollectionChanged.

so for the purpose of subscription to event you can cast ItemsSource to INotifyCollectionChanged:

```
var list = ItemsSource as INotifyCollectionChanged;
if (list != null)
    list.CollectionChanged += list_CollectionChanged;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. you saved my day.